# Using Web Part when adding document to a library

Tags: visual-studio, 2007, web-part

When a user uploads a document to a SharePoint library, I need to present them with a few dropdowns and text fields where they can provide some extra info. The dropdowns are going to be populated from a database.

The way I have currently gone about this is create a Web Part which displays a user control. The user control contains the dropdowns. I can add the Web Part to a SharePoint page and it works as expected (pulls data from DB and displays in UC).

However I need this page to display after they have uploaded a document to a library. Would this be achieved using a Workflow?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the "Edit Form" for your document library, add your webpart to the Edit Form and ensure that a column is marked as "Required" (so that when a document is uploaded, the Edit form is displayed).

Comment: Thanks. I am able to edit the 'Forms/AllItems.aspx' page via 'Site Actions', however that option doesn't appear when I am in 'Forms/EditForm.aspx'

Comment: Hm, didn't know that it can be done in such way :) The only idea I though of is to create event receiver that would be fired after item was added redirecting to page with web part.

Comment: Andriy, I've also had the idea of redirecting when ItemAdded is raised using a event receiver. However how do I add a new page to sharepoint? Can that be done?

Comment: Highly recommend you look at WSPBuilder for simple deployment of files (like Application Pages) to the LAYOUTS folder.

Comment: Disregard my last comment, didn't see you were using Visual Studio 2010, create a mapped folder in your solution which points to Layouts, and put your application page there. Then you can access it via http://<site>/<web>/_layouts/yourpage.aspx

Comment: Sorry I tagged it wrong, it's for SP2007 and I'm using VS2008.

Comment: Yes, as James suggested. And by the way James is it posible for your page to display http://<site>/<web>/yourpage.aspx insted of http://<site>/<web>/_layouts/yourpage.aspx, beacuse having "layouts" in Url path is kind of odd for me.

Comment: Don't think it is possible, as it's a mapped path in IIS. Perfectly normal in a SharePoint environment to have _layouts anyway, nearly every settings page is located in layouts. In 2010, you'd probably use a Modal Dialog if you wanted to hide the the URL from your users.

Comment: To add webparts onto EditFrom.aspx, use the ToolPaneView=2 URL parameter. Ex: EditForm.aspx?ToolPaneView=2

Answer (score 0):

Just following on from James L's suggestion of editing the EditForm.aspx, while the "Edit Page" menu item doesn't appear on the Site Actions menu, you can still trick the page into edit mode.

1. Browse to the edit page for a particular list item
2. Paste the following javascript snippet into the browsers address bar

javascript:MSOLayout_ChangeLayoutMode(false)

1. You should see the page in edit mode where you can then add your web part

Works in IE, haven't tried other browsers.